# How to attach external fingerprint scanner with USB in react native for android application?

Tags: react-native, scanning, android-fingerprint-api

I am working on an application related to attendance, where multiple employees can mark their attendance on a single android phone. I want to attach an external fingerprint scanner with USB. I am building my application in react native. 
I got the solution in Java but I need the solution in react native. 
I need the solution like this link but in react native.
https://medium.com/touch4it/fingerprint-external-scanner-with-usb-database-sdk-64c3ec5ea82d

Comment: Does solution in Java works ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll  need to bridge between React Native (Javascript) and native (Java) code. [The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios) are pretty good and have specific [examples for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android).

One approach would be to fork a react-native biometric integration library (for example https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner) and replace the underlying native (Java for android) implementation with the code that you found.